# How to turn off focus on a canvas to allow mouse clicks on items visibly under it

Tags: html5-canvas, focus

Canvas has a .focus() method that's supposed to be able to take an object such as:

```
myCanvas.focus({focusVisible: false});
```

This executes without an error, but mouse clicks are still captured at the canvas level.

focusVisible is defined as:
A boolean value that should be set to true to force visible indication that the element is focused. By default, or if the property is not true, a browser may still provide visible indication if it determines that this would improve accessibility for users.

It isn't exactly saying it will turn focus on and off as I would like, so is there some way to allow mouse clicks to hit the visible items below the transparent canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Sprinkle some CSS (preferred):

```css
.my-canvas {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Or apply the style directly in JS (not preferred):

```js
myCanvas.style.pointerEvents = 'none'
```